# Java OutputStream issue while sending HTTP responses with cyrrilic symbols

Tags: java, http, encoding, client-server, outputstream

I have a question about sending a russian text via HTTP in Java.
Looks like the problem is connected with the encoding.

I have an HTTP Server imlemented in Java:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8001), 0);
    ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    server.createContext("/", new  MyHttpHandler());
    server.setExecutor(threadPoolExecutor);
    server.start();
   System.out.println(" Server started on port 8001");

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

And the `MyHttpHandler` class

```
class MyHttpHandler implements HttpHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {

        String requestParamValue = null;

        if("GET".equals(httpExchange.getRequestMethod()) && httpExchange.getRequestURI().toString().equals("/get-first")) {
            requestParamValue = handleGetRequest(httpExchange);
        }
        System.out.println("Message to the client sent successfully");
    }
    private String handleGetRequest(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
        String s = "Hello!";
        httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200,s.length());
        OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
        os.write(s.getBytes());
        os.close();
        return "OK";
    }
```

And when I start my server and open the browser and type in a search line: http://localhost:8001/get-first i get the message: Hello!

BUT! As soon as I change `s = "Привет!"` or change it that way it contains any russian symbol, i don't get any answer at all and while debugging my program stops at `os.write(s.getBytes())`

I used some method of manual encoding like this:

```
String myString = "some cyrillic text";
byte bytes[] = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); 
String value = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

But unfortunately it didn' work out.
Please help me in solving that issue guys!

Comment: The length in `sendResponseHeaders()` needs to agree with the actual length written in bytes. When you have Cyrillic text the number of characters won't agree with the number of bytes. You should have used `s.getBytes().length` instead of `s.length()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! Have a nice day